# HTMX hx-trigger two functions

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

I have a selected dropdown list that triggers a function in my Django application.

So I need to execute another function too. is it possible?

this is the HTML code I tried to use hx-trigger with load after 0.5s but is executed once before the user selects the item!

then I moved the function inside the page that it run after the user selects the item. it works but the returned request is duplicated! and I need it to replace the old list?

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="custom-select mb-4" name="fields" hx-get="{% url 'select_field' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#Wells" hx-include="[name='Toggle']">
                <option selected>Select a field</option>
                {% for Field in TFTFields %}
                <option ue="{{Field.Perimeter}}">{{Field.Perimeter}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <div id="Wells">
                {% include 'Home/Data_visa/part_Wells.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-12" >
    <div id="part_MyWellsList">
        {% include 'Home/Data_visa/part_MyWellsList.html' %}
</div>
    </div>
```

And this is my `part_Wells.html` page

```
    <div class="col-md-3" >
    <select class="custom-select mb-4" name="Wells" hx-get="{% url 'addplotly' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#plotly_production" hx-include="[name='Toggle']">
        <option selected>Select Well</option>
        {% for well in TFTWells %}
        <option value="{{well.WellID}}">{{well.WellID}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"
  hx-target="#part_MyWellsList" 
  hx-get="{% url 'LoadWells' %}" 
  hx-trigger="load"
  hx-include="[name='fields']"
  hx-swap="afterend">
</div>
```

and this `part_MyWellsList` page:

```
{% if FieldWells %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" >
    <select class="custom-select mb-4" name="Wells1" hx-get="{% url 'addplotly' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#plotly_production" hx-include="[name='Toggle']">
        <option selected>Select Well</option>
        {% for well in FieldWells %}
        <option value="{{well.WellID}}">{{well.WellID}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

with this structure everything in the backend works well just I need the last dropdown list to be replaced with the new one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making these changes.
the main page:

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="custom-select mb-4" name="fields" hx-get="{% url 'select_field' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#Wells" hx-include="[name='Toggle']">
                <option selected>Select a field</option>
                {% for Field in TFTFields %}
                <option ue="{{Field.Perimeter}}">{{Field.Perimeter}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" >
            <div id="Wells">
                {% include 'Home/Data_visa/part_Wells.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-12" >
    <div id="part_MyWellsList">
    </div>
</div>
```

and also in the second pages as:

```
<div class="col-md-12"
hx-target="#part_MyWellsList"
hx-get="{% url 'LoadWells' %}" 
hx-trigger="load"
hx-include="[name='fields']"
hx-swap="innerHTML">
{% include 'Home/Data_visa/part_MyWellsList.html' %} 
</div>
```